# How to request API in Capacitor App created by Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, capacitor

I created Capacitor App by existing Nuxt.js project and use `dist` folder which is generated by executing `nuxt generate`.
When I run App, API request respond html file below

```
var ExceptionCode;
(function (ExceptionCode) {
    /**
     * API is not implemented.
     *
     * This usually means the API can't be used because it is not implemented for
     * the current platform.
     */
    ExceptionCode["Unimplemented"] = "UNIMPLEMENTED";
    /**
     * API is not available.
     *
     * This means the API can't be used right now because:
     *   - it is currently missing a prerequisite, such as network connectivity
     *   - it requires a particular platform or browser version`
```

API is called like `this.$axios.$post('/api/example')`.

I tried to add `this.$axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://example.com"` just before `this.$axios.$post('/api/example')` but didn't work.

How could I get API request correctly like it does on web sites?

Comment: You can't do this with pregenerated dist alone. You need a running node server to access nuxt api endpoints. "but didn't work"- this can work if you really run nuxt server on example.com and have CORS configured